# Android : how to play multiple audios using single media player object

Tags: android, media-player

I need to create only one media player object `Mediaplayer mp = new Mediaplayer();`
Using this I need to play multiple audio files one after the other for that i am using handler
and getting the duration.

If i create multiple media player objects it shows error(1, -17)

I also need to display images related to audio files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rule out SoundPool?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

It typically good for short audio clips.

Comment: it doesnot play audio files properly

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `OnCompletionListener` and register it with your `MediaPlayer` instance.

After the media has been played out it will call this callback method `onCompletion`

```
void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
   //Here you stop it.
   mp.stop();
   //Reset the data source path to the new file
   mp.setDataSource(<uri>);
   mp.prepare(); // or mp.prepareAsync();
   // start the mediaplayer after the prepare has completed.
}
```

Release the mediaplayer instance once you are done playing all the files.

Comment: this approach could cause crash of MP. Even if you stop() MP and after that setDataSource(<uri>) - this method could cause a crash. You have to reset() MP after stop() (which doesn't guarantee that no crash would happen as well) or every time release() used MP and create another instance for every audio track.